# Export image from Google Earth Engine to my drive

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I  have created code that takes the reflectance of Landsat8 and clip it with Iraq's borders. the problem is that I can't export it to drive and I get this error messege:

> Scale must be greater than 0.010000 m/pixel

I took the scale from the data catalog, but it may be that I haven't fully understood the scale idea/logic.

This is the code I wrote:

```
// Load a Iraq boundary from a Fusion Table.
var Iraq = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('Country', 'Iraq'));
print(Iraq)
Map.addLayer(Iraq, {}, 'Iraq from fusion table');  

// Load a Landsat 8 -atmospheric corrected
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR') 
//surface reflectance
    .filterBounds(Iraq)
    .filterDate('2015-03-01', '2018-03-31');

// Get the number of images.
var count = collection.size();
print('Count: ', count);

// Sort by a cloud cover property, get the least cloudy image.
//var image = ee.Image(collection.sort('CLOUD_COVER').first());
//print('Least cloudy image: ', image);

// make a composite (mean image) of the images 
var meanImage = collection.mean().clip(Iraq);
print(meanImage);

//make image for mesopotamia only
var mesopotamia=meanImage.clip(table);

//visualization
var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};

Map.addLayer(meanImage,visParams,'Landset8');
Map.addLayer(mesopotamia,visParams,'Mesopotamia');

  // Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: meanImage,
  description: 'IraqLandsat8',
  scale:0.0001,
  region: Iraq
});

  // Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mesopotamia,
  description: 'IraqLandsat8',
  scale:0.0001,
  region: table
});
```

Comment: The error message seems direct enough. Exporting even centimeter imagery at tenth millimeter scale increases storage by 10k/pixel. Landsat 8 30m imagery is increased by 90Gb/pixel. How many petabytes of disk do you have, and how many years do your have to download it?

Comment: All Landsat 8 band scales are 30m, except for `pan` band that is 15m, why would you export in less than that?

Comment: yeah I know it is 30m but I saw in their website that for some reason it is written as the scale so it confused me. Do you know what does this 0/0001 means in the band scale?

Comment: Scale, in this case, is pixel resolution, isn't the classical cartographic scale. Change `scale: 30,` and try again. It should work

Comment: @ReutKeller, as Aldo says, scale means pixel resolution, so you are trying to export the image with a resolution of 1 cm, so each landsat pixel will result in 9 million pixels.. that is too much.